# IIS 7.x server error with HTTPS deployement

Tags: .net, angular, https, deployment, iis-7.5

Am using IIS V7.5 with windows server for deploying Angular + .Net 4.5 fullStack application.

Am using multiple instances at same site with different versions of application in order to make additional test !

all sites are deployed on same host with https and different ports each for frontend and backend (frontend part and backend part are deployed seperately ) as shown below :

[image: Architecture of deployement]

Before two months : all instance were deployed all as same structure but using http for all , and nothing happened ( everthing is working fine )

my problem is , when i changed instances to use https , of course with changing build for appropriate link , i get errors and frontend can't communicate with backend anymore !
is it a problem related to IIS and https and multiple instances ?

Comment: People deploy HTTPS sites on IIS for more than two decades. So before asking around, your very first task should be understanding more about the errors and learn what the error messages/call stacks mean. There are already tons of threads on Stack Overflow on various kinds of related Angular errors.

Comment: The SSL certificate is generally given at the api, and its link address is https://, which needs to be processed in the front end. What changes did you make when configuring your Angular project for local https access? What error are you getting?

Comment: @JennyDai Thanks for replying , i have just modified the enviroment file used later for build ( npm run build ... ) that file now have links like /api and other paths with https : 
like https://mydomain.xxx/api 
am not getting really a syntaxic error other other , its a hidden logical error , frontend and can't communicate anymore with backend

Comment: For this question, I would prefer to know what error message you were getting at that time

Comment: I think it is related to file web.config inside dist after building the frontend part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for this issue , as so many developpers can face it in the future :
I have changed to file Web.config (XML File ) inside the folder dist of the build of the frontend part before deplyoing it on iis :

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>



<!--START REDIRECT TO HTTPS-->
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<!--END REDIRECT TO HTTPS-->



<!--START REDIRECT TO ROOT-->
<rule name="Angular routes" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(token)" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(userguide.cshtml)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
<!--END REDIRECT TO ROOT-->



</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note : For IIS version 7.x.x and 6.x.x and windows Server 2012 R2 This error is confirmed .